# How to display all the squares I draw in the regionplot

Tags: plotting

the RT1 is a matrix of squares in different location. I draw 25 squares, but some of them can not displayed. I guess because the square is to little to display in this big region{{x,-15,15},{y,-15,15}}. Because When I decrease the plotregion, the square in this place can be displayed.
How can I let all of them be displayed in one picture?

```
L = 1;(*the wide of rectangle*)
W = 2;(*the lenght of rectangle*)
Ldistance = 5;
Wdistance = 5;
Xrelative = 0;
Yrelative = 3;
seta = {11*Pi/12, 1*Pi/12} 
Table[RegionPlot[(y - (Tan[seta[[i]]]*x + W/2/Abs[Cos[seta[[i]]]]) <= 
     0) && (y - (Tan[seta[[i]]]*x - W/2/Abs[Cos[seta[[i]]]]) >= 
     0) && (y - Tan[seta[[i]] - Pi/2]*(x - L/2/Cos[seta[[i]]]) <= 
     0) && (y - Tan[seta[[i]] - Pi/2]*(x + L/2/Cos[seta[[i]]]) >= 
     0), {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}], {i, 1, 
  2}] (*two diffrent angle rectangle
*)
R1[m_, n_] := (y - 
     n - (Tan[seta[[1]]]*(x - m) + W/2/Abs[Cos[seta[[1]]]]) <= 
    0) && (y - 
     n - (Tan[seta[[1]]]*(x - m) - W/2/Abs[Cos[seta[[1]]]]) >= 
    0) && (y - n - 
     Tan[seta[[1]] - Pi/2]*(x - m - L/2/Cos[seta[[1]]]) <= 
    0) && (y - n - 
     Tan[seta[[1]] - Pi/2]*(x - m + L/2/Cos[seta[[1]]]) >= 
    0);(* the matrix of rectangle with the same angle
*)R2[m_, n_] := (y - Yrelative - 
     n - (Tan[seta[[2]]]*(x - Xrelative - m) + 
       W/2/Abs[Cos[seta[[2]]]]) <= 
    0) && (y - Yrelative - 
     n - (Tan[seta[[2]]]*(x - Xrelative - m) - 
       W/2/Abs[Cos[seta[[2]]]]) >= 
    0) && (y - Yrelative - n - 
     Tan[seta[[2]] - Pi/2]*(x - Xrelative - m - L/2/Cos[seta[[2]]]) <=
     0) && (y - Yrelative - n - 
     Tan[seta[[2]] - Pi/2]*(x - Xrelative - m + L/2/Cos[seta[[2]]]) >=
     0); (*the matrix of rectangle with the another same angle
*)
RT1 = Table[R1[i, j], {i, -10, 10, 5}, {j, -10, 10, 5}]; 
RT2 = Table[R2[i, j], {i, -15, 15, 5}, {j, -15, 15, 5}];
RegionPlot[RT1, {x, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}](* plot the 25 rectangles *)
```

[image]

Comment: Without the definition of `RT1` then I can't test it out, but try this:  Instead of `Show[ Table[ RegionPlot[ ...], {i, 5}, {j, 5} ] ]` , do `RegionPlot[ Table[ ... , {i,5}, {j, 5}] ]`.  Or try just adding `PlotRange -> {{-11, 11}, {-11, 11}}` as an option to `Show`

Comment: Hello Jason I still can not let all the squares displayed on it as you said. I paste my code on it. Could you help me where I made a mistake?

Comment: Don't use a screenshot, paste the code as text if you want someone to test it out....

Comment: Please post your actual _Mathematica_ code, not an image of it. Without real code no one will be able to work with it to see what you might have done wrong, nor will they be able to experiment with possible repairs.

Comment: Sorry about that.

Comment: Great - now that we have the code and the plotted output, can you say what exactly you are looking for?  Do you want the rectangles from the top two plots to show up in the bottom plot?

Comment: I want the same 25 rectangles with the same angle show in one picture. Some of them can not be displayed. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your `RT1` is a matrix whose rows each have five plottable regions defined by conditional expressions, but when you plot them

```
RegionPlot[#, {x, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}] & /@ RT1
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

only some of them plot.  One way to fix this is to simply use a higher number of [`PlotPoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotPoints.html)

```
RegionPlot[RT1, {x, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Edit

One last point, you can combine all the predicates for each row of `RT1` by using [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) in combination with [`Or`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Or.html), resulting in a plot of only 5 regions, with 5 colors,

```
RegionPlot[Evaluate[Or @@@ RT1], {x, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}, 
 PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This also plots a good deal faster